# R function to compare two vectors. Works in repex but not when applied to my data

Tags: r

## What I want to do:

I have two vectors. The first one contains a minimum temperature and the second one contains the maximum temperature.
The function I wrote is supposed to compare these, line by line, and for each line return the one with the greater absolute value (without actually applying abs() to it).
But:
If their absolute values are equal (e.g. max = 5, min = -5), it should return NA.
If they are both 0, it should return 0.

## The problem:

My problem is that it never returns 0 even if it should. It returns NA instead. When I tried to make a repex, I could not recreate the problem. It works on small vectors I created. It even works fine on subsets of my data, but when I apply it to the full set of data, it doesn't.

## What I tried:

I added some print statements in the function itself and the for loop that applies the function to my data to find cases in which 0 should be returned.
When applied to the full set, it gives me NAs where there should be 0.
When I created a subset of the data in which this happens, the function suddenly worked.
When I invented some data to test the function, it worked as well.
I tried restarting Rstudio, deleting the workspace, hidden objects included. The problem remains.

## The function:

```
# invent some data:
mins_ <- c(0,0,-4,-5,7,10)
maxs_ <- c(0,-1,4,-5,12,-5)


# my function:
# I edited my function according to docendo discimus' answer (thanks!)
# it's more readable now, but the problem is still there.
# Here's the updated function:

getmaxmin <- function(vmax,vmin){
  # create vector to store the results
  dTmp10_minmax <- numeric(length = length(vmax))
  for (i in 1:length(dTmp10_minmax)) {
    # if both are zero, store zero
    if ((vmax[i] == 0) == T & (vmin[i] == 0) == T){
      # print statement to find the cases where this is supposed to happen:
      print(i)
      dTmp10_minmax[i] <- 0
    } else {
      # if both are equal but not zero, store NA in vector
      if (vmin[i] != 0 & vmax[i] != 0 & abs(vmax[i]) == abs(vmin[i]) ) {
        dTmp10_minmax[i] <- NA
      } else {
        if (abs(vmax[i]) < abs(vmin[i])) {
          dTmp10_minmax[i] <- vmin[i]
        } else {
          if (abs(vmax[i]) > abs(vmin[i])) {
            dTmp10_minmax[i] <- vmax[i]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(dTmp10_minmax)
}

# apply to data
test <- getmaxmin(vmin = mins_, vmax = maxs_)

# result:
> test
[1]  0 -1 NA NA 12 10

# as you can see, this works fine, but when I try applying it to my list of 
# datasets, it returns NA where there should be 0
# I apply it like this:

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  d_Temp_p3_10minmax <- getmaxmin(vmax = datas[[i]]$d_Temp_p3_10max, vmin = datas[[i]]$d_Temp_p3_10min)
  print(paste("data",i))
  datas[[i]] <- cbind(datas[[i]], d_Temp_p3_10minmax)
}

# datas is a list of 45 large datasets, file_list is a character vector
# containing the names of these sets
```

There are neither warnings nor error messages. The function works on parts of the data but not when applied via for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to simplify your function considerably which will make debugging easier and the function execution more efficient since you'll be using vectorized functions as R was designed.

```
foo = function(x, y) {
  res = pmax(abs(x), abs(y))
  res[abs(x) == abs(y)] = NA
  res[x == 0 & y == 0] = 0
  res
}

foo(mins_, maxs_)
# [1]  0  1 NA NA 12 10
```

Edit:

if you want to preserve the signs, you can adjust the above function to something like the following:

```
foo = function(x, y) {
  res = pmax(abs(x), abs(y))
  res[abs(x) == abs(y)] = NA
  res[x == 0 & y == 0] = 0
  idx_not_abs_x = res != abs(x) & !is.na(res) & res != 0
  res[idx_not_abs_x] = res[idx_not_abs_x] * sign(y[idx_not_abs_x])
  res[!idx_not_abs_x] = res[!idx_not_abs_x] * sign(x[!idx_not_abs_x])
  res
}

foo(mins_, maxs_)
#[1]  0 -1 NA NA 12 10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is certainly much more elegant! I updated my question accordingly. The problem itself still remains though.

Comment: I just realized that this actually doesn't do the exact same thing as my original function. My code was supposed to preserve the algebraic sign. I will try to modify the function you suggested to do so. In the meantime I put my original function back up. Thanks though!